# Project is not compiling with round_page in Objective-c for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, posix

When I am trying to use round_page() function in my project, it stops compiling and says that there is linker problem. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should add a library to your project, what contains this method. What is your error?

Comment: I don't see any reference on iOS for that function.  Possibly you're using something that doesn't exist (in spite of being tagged 'posix').

Comment: You must show what the linker problem is.  We can't second-guess what you're doing or what it is complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I realized that i just had to include mach/mach-init.h